# Is buoyant force self-adjusting?

Tags: forces, definition, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

Assume that density of the body is less than the fluid.

If we put a body in a given fluid the buoyant force equalise the weight of the body. If we increase weight, the buoyant force increase?

If it does So it must be self-adjusting force, is it have any maximum value just like friction as?

Comment: @5 Dots buoyant force by a particular liquid will increase only if the volume of the body inside the liquid is increased.

Comment: @Ankit, Imagine a floating boat. The fact that it's floating means that the buoyant force on it is equal to its weight. Then, imagine you drop a sack of sand into the boat. Now it weighs more. but is it still floating? If so, then then the buoyant force _must_ have increased. It must have increased by exactly the same as the weight of the sack of sand. "Yes but,..." I hear you say, "that's because more of the boat now is 'inside the liquid.'" Uh Huh! And that equilibrium between its weight, and how much of it is "in the liquid" is precisely what the OP is trying to understand.

Comment: @Solomon Slow oo now I get what OP is looking out for.

Answer (score 8):

Like you said, the bouyant force is equal to the weight of the displaced water. Making the object heavier will sink it further until either a new equilibrium is reached by displacing more water to counteract the increase in weight or the entire object is submerged, but the equilibrium is still not reached. The maximum value would be the weight of the water with the same volume as the object.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the weight of the object doesn't change the buoyant force. The buoyant force only depends on the submerged volume of the object and the density of the fluid it is in. Changing only the weight of the object will just determine if the object will float or sink given the constant buoyant force.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: If it's floating (which it is because the density is less than the fluid's density), increasing the weight makes it go down which increases the submerged volume... that's kinda important to mention...

Comment: @user253751 nothing in my answer contradicts that. *Only* changing the weight doesn't change the buoyant force. I didn't say increasing the weight and then allowing things to change accordingly doesn't change the resulting buoyant force. Furthermore, the OP's problem doesn't say the object is partially submerged (you can hold any object under a fluid completely), and the OP doesn't say *after* we increase the weight we allow for anything else to happen. I read the problem literally, not adding in my own assumptions.

Comment: Well lots of things are possible if you stop time. If you only make the incline steeper, does the ball roll faster? No! Why not? Because you didn't give it time to accelerate! If you only pour water on the floor, does the floor get wet? No! Why not? Because the water hasn't fallen out of the container yet! This is extremely silly pedantry.

Comment: So if you pour water on the floor, the floor doesn't get wet?

Comment: @user253751 It's not pedantry? I am only using what the OP stated. I am not adding in any additional assumptions. If you have an object in a fluid and you only increase the weight the buoyant force does not increase. That is a true statement.

Comment: @user253751 I think this conversation is done if you are going to twist my words around. Thanks for the input

Comment: Hey man, is there any case in which buoyant force increase or let put it simply,  does there any case in which it act like self adjusting force as friction does

Comment: @BioPhysicist In order for an object to float, the buoyant force has to equal the weight of the object, does it not?

Comment: @BobD Yes, that is the case

Comment: @5Dots The buoyant force is determined by how much of the object is submerged. So if by the fact that the force changes when the amount submerged changes you mean it is a self-adjusting force, then yes it is one of those. I am not sure what you mean by that term though.

Comment: @BioPhysicist OK. Then if I have two objects and one object weighs more than the other but both objects float, then the buoyant force is greater for the heavier object, since it displaces more water than the lighter object. Correct?

Comment: @BobD Yes, that would be true, but that scenario isn't explicitly stated by the OP. The OP says nothing about floating. If you have an object in a fluid, and *all you do* is change the weight of the object, then the buoyant force will not change. Other users here are assuming that other things happen after the weight change that are not stated in the question. If the OP clarified then I would edit / delete my answer.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Now I understand the basis of your answer. To me, I assumed the OP was talking about floating objects since the OP specifically stated that "the density of the object is less than the density of the fluid" and that is a condition for floating. Anyway , that is the basis of my answer and I suspect it is the basis of Syen Curkovic answer. Regards,

Comment: @BobD I wouldn't be surprised if this is what the OP meant. If so, they should edit the question to be clearer on this point.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Agree.

Comment: OP says both "Assume that density of the body is less than the fluid." and "the buoyant force equalise the weight of the body". How is that compatible with anything other that floating?  If you submerged such an object, the buoyant force would be greater than the weight of the body.

Comment: @Brick Even if the object was floating *only* increasing the weight would not change the buoyant force. Changing the weight, letting the object move, letting oscillations dissipate, etc. and then looking at the buoyant force, then yes, you would see a different value. However, the OP does not outline this specific scenario, so I'm not going to assume it.

Answer (score 1):

> If we put a body in a given fluid the buoyant force equalise the
> weight of the body. If we increase weight, the buoyant force increase?

Correct. As long as the density of the object is less than or equal to the density of the liquid.

> So it must be self adjusting force, is it have any maximum value just
> like friction as??

Not exactly sure what you mean by "self adjusting", but the buoyant force does have to increase in order for a heavier object to float. But there is a maximum buoyant force which occurs when the density of the object equals the density of the liquid. I don't see this as analogous to a maximum friction force, by which I assume you mean static friction force. The static friction force does match the applied force to prevent relative motion between the surfaces up to a maximum possible static friction force. Clearly, the buoyant force does not prevent relative motion between the surface of the object and the liquid because the heavier object will submerge further than the lighter object until equilibrium is established.

In any case, in order for an object to float, the upward buoyant force must equal the weight of the object. In other words, in order to float the following equation must be satisfied for all cases where the density of the object is less than or equal to the density of the liquid.

$$V_{o}ρ_{o}g=V_{l}ρ_{l}g$$

The left side of the equation is the weight of the object. $V_o$ is the total volume of the object, which is not necessarily the submerged volume, and $ρ_{o}$ is the density of the object.

The right side of the equation is the buoyant force, which is the weight of the volume of liquid $V_l$ that is displaced by the object times the density of the liquid, $ρ_{l}$.

The greater the weight of the object on the left side of the equation the greater the buoyant force has to be on the right in order for the object to float. The maximum buoyant force occurs when the density of the object equals the density of the liquid, $ρ_{o}=ρ_{l}$, meaning the volume of water displaced equals the volume of the object, $V_{l}=V_{o}$ and the object floats completely submerged. Any further increase in weight results in the object sinking and no further displacement of water, so the buoyant force remains constant. Adding weight simply causes the object to sink faster (assuming the density of the liquid is constant).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it, thanks mate